# Building Tic Tac Toe Game in Javascript - removing events when certain field is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to build a tic tac toe game and right now I struggle to make an 'X' permanently appear after the field 'section1' is clicked. Otherwise, the 'X' should appear and disappear as it does right now. I tried to add addEventHandler, but unfortunately couldn't come up with a working solution also, I m sure it's very simple. Here is my code:

```js
let one = document.getElementById('one')

let XonMouseEnter = function() {
  one.innerHTML = 'X';
}

let XonMouseOut = function() {
  one.innerHTML = '';
}

one.onmouseenter = XonMouseEnter;

one.onmouseleave = XonMouseOut;

one.addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    /*not sure about the code*/
  }
)
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 200px)/ repeat(3, 200px);
  /*border: 1px solid black;**/
  /*width: 600px;*/
}

.contONE {
  grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.contTWO {
  grid-area: 1/2/2/3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}

.contTHREE {
  grid-area: 1/3/2/4;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}

.contFOUR {
  grid-area: 2/1/3/2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
}

.contFIVE {
  grid-area: 2/2/3/3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}

.contSIX {
  grid-area: 2/3/3/4;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

.contSEVEN {
  grid-area: 3/1/4/2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}

.contEIGHT {
  grid-area: 3/2/4/3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}

.contNINE {
  grid-area: 3/3/4/4;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/fab/Downloads/1108/1108.css">
  <title>Working of 11.08</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="contONE" id="one">
      Section1
    </div>

    <div class="contTWO">
      Section2
    </div>


    <div class="contTHREE">
      Section3
    </div>
    <div class="contFOUR">
      Section4
    </div>


    <div class="contFIVE">
      Section5
    </div>

    <div class="contSIX">
      Section6
    </div>


    <div class="contSEVEN">
      Section7
    </div>

    <div class="contEIGHT">
      Section8
    </div>

    <div class="contNINE">
      Section9
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks everyone for reading or even helping a beginner out!

Comment: Use `addEventListener` consistently, for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events as well as the `click`. Then you can use `removeEventListener`.

Comment: thank you, that worked!